# Href not working in GSP pages

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using modal box plugin with grails. The problem is that the link that it creates does not always call the server side code.

here is the link on the page

```
<modalbox:createLink 
controller="company" 
    action="setChangeCompanyAdmin" 
    absolute="true" 
mapping="changeAdmin" 
id="${companyInstance.id}" 
title="Change Primary Admin" 
width="600" 
linkname="Change Primary Admin" />
```

The action in the controller is preparing a list in the certain way to be displayed in the popup that the modal box opens. But the problem is that the server side is not being called every time, only in IE.

I have tried absolute and specifying a mapping as well but to no avail.

Also i have set the page attributes in the gsp page to not cache the data at all.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

But even this does not seem to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Adhir

Comment: have you already taken a look at the plugin's source code?

Answer (score 0):

The browser is still caching your request. You can add a parameter of the current time stamp to the request.

```
<modalbox:createLink 
controller="company" 
    action="setChangeCompanyAdmin" 
    absolute="true" 
    params="${cacheKiller: new Date()​.time​}"
mapping="changeAdmin" 
id="${companyInstance.id}" 
title="Change Primary Admin" 
width="600" 
linkname="Change Primary Admin" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably IE caching the response.  If you want to disable caching via the controller's response object, the following code should work:

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store")
```